# Assigned To field won't populate using content query

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part, tasks

- I am using a content query web part to roll up a group of tasks to the higher level site.
- I am using a custom item style template.

  ```
  <xsl:template name="TasksView" match="Row[@Style='TasksView']" mode="itemstyle">    
      <TABLE border='1' style='table-layout:fixed;' width='100%'> 
          <TR bgcolor='#003e74'>
              <TD style='font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;width:30%'>Title</TD>                     
              <TD style='font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff'>Start Date</TD>
              <TD style='font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff'>Due Date</TD>                                                
              <TD style='font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff'>Task Status</TD>
              <TD style='font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff'>% Complete</TD>
              <TD style='font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;border-right:1px'>Assigned To</TD>
          </TR>   
          <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="@Title" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="@StartDate" /></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="@DueDate" /></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="@Status" /></td>
              <td><xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="@PercentComplete!=0">
                      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@PercentComplete,'##.%')"/>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:value-of select="concat('0','%')"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
              </td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="@AssignedTo" /></td>
           </tr>  
      </TABLE>                                                    
  </xsl:template>
  ```

I was initially having a lot of troubles with the item style, which was copied over from another site that it is being used on.  I had to strip out a lot of formatting.

Here is what my Content Query mapping looks like:

[image]

The `Assigned To` field is coming through correct as I'm not getting the error message of `The site or list column "..." does not exist or is not valid.`  It also will change it back to `Assigned To` if I use `AssignedTo` or `Assigned To [Core Task and Issue Columns]`.

I don't know what would be preventing this value to come across.  Everything seems mapped correctly and the fields are populated in the actual items.

I am also unable to format the dates. When I use `<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@StartDate), 1033, 'MM/dd/yyyy')"/>` in place of `<xsl:value-of select="@StartDate" />` it breaks the web part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this figured by moving the `AssignedTo` column in `Site Columns` to the `Custom Columns` group and then moving it back to where it was (`Core Task and Issue Columns`).

It must have not being picked up for whatever reason and needed to be reset.